# Wordpress pagination issues(going back to page 1)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm having some trouble with the pagination on my Wordpress blog. It's work perfectly fine, the only thing is that it won't go back to page 1. I can go to page 2, 3, 4 and back. The only page I can't navigate back to is page 1. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Much thanks in advance!

This is what generates the pagination:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'format' => '/blog/page/%#%',
        'end_size' => 10,
        'current' => 0,     
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>
```

Comment: Same here! Please help!